# Как применить значение функции скрипта в html?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Используется Spring MVC + Angular.

Есть табличка пользователей в html:

```
...<thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>NAME</th>
                        <th>AGE</th>
                        <th>ADMIN</th>
                        <th>CREATED_DATE</th>
                        <th width="100"></th>
                        <th width="100"></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="u in ctrl.getAllUsers()">
                        <td>{{u.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{u.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{u.age}}</td>
                        <td>{{u.admin}}</td>
                        <body>
                            <td>getDate({{u.createdDate}})</td>
                        </body>
                        <script>
                            function getDate(timestamp) {
                                return new Date(timestamp * 1e3).toISOString().slice(-13, -5);
                            }
                        </script>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.editUser(u.id)" class="btn btn-success custom-width">
                                Edit
                            </button>
                        </td>...
```

метод ctrl.getAllUsers обращается к Controller'у возвращающих юзеров и соответственно в цикле отображает информацию о каждом юзере. Но значение u.createdDate - unix timestamp. Я бы хотел отображать в более читаемой форме. Для этого в html странице объявил скрипт:

```
<script>
    function getDate(timestamp) {
        return new Date(timestamp * 1e3).toISOString().slice(-13, -5);
    }
</script>
```

и попытался его вызвать:

```
<body>
    <td>getDate({{u.createdDate}})</td>
</body>
```

Но он отображает значение непосредственно строки.

Подскажите, каким образом можно вызвать функцию и отобразить возвращаемый ей параметр?

P.S. В технологиях фронта разбираюсь плохо, возможно есть более корректные способы для отображения времени в корректном формате, когда от сервера приходит значение timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для angularjs есть фильтр [date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) :

вместо

```
<td>getDate({{u.createdDate}})</td>
```

пишем, например

```
{{u.createdDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}
```

Comment: Не знал. Спасибо за совет. Почитаю доку, проверю.